# Index and match on multiple columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup

I have the following dataset I am trying to re-sort to do a mailing merge with word.  I need to suppress the empty cells and match the usernames in an array to the company name they belong to.

im using the following solution to match the first criteria

```
=INDEX(CompanyName,MATCH(1,MMULT(--(Attendee=G4),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(Attendee)^0)),0))
```

But that means i have to type in the user name before i can match the company

and

```
=INDEX(Attendee,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($G$4:I4,list),0))
```

Gives me the usernames in a horizontal list.... but i need it to list in a vertical format

```
ecompany name, user1, user2, user3, user4, user5, user6, user7
company1, bob, sue, dave, , ,john, mary
company2, dave, barry, steve, dan, , , pete
```

i would like the data to appear in two columns for a mailing merge

```
Company Name, User
company1, bob
company1, sue
company1, dave
company1, john
company1, mary
company2, dave
company2, dave
company2, barry
company2, steve
company2, dan
company2, pete
```

i hope this makes sense?

[image]

here is the outcome im looking for in an example. Unfortunately it needs the name in the first column prepopulated before it will match to the user.

OUTPUT SAMPLE:

[image: OUTPUT SAMPLE]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research & understanding of the problem being solved. Please edit to either a) clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it or b) include attempted solutions plus why they didn't work. In either case, be sure your expected results are clearly presented.

Comment: Ive added the information requested

Comment: Ive also added a picture of my current working sheet

Comment: Cool. I inlined it for you. I don't think new users can do that themselves.

Comment: Thanks! all help is appreciated. i tried to give a smuch info .. i know im missing something obvious in the formula.

Comment: How many attendee columns are there? And how often must you perform this task? I'm wondering how much trouble it's worth going to to avoid the somewhat obvious step of writing a simple concatenation and then manually cutting & pasting 6 columns of data into one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. This is still a 'dumb' way, but it only requires one easy manual step and actually meets spec in that it presents your results in two columns as requested.

Data:
[image: DATA]

### STEP 1:

I defined named ranges COMPANIES F2:F99 and NAMES L2:AB99

### STEP 2:

Here's your output:
[image: OUTPUT]

With formula in column B:

```
=INDEX(NAMES,ROUNDUP((ROW()-1)/17,0),MOD(ROW()-2,17)+1)
```

It's just an nth-column/every n rows formula with n manually set to 17 (you could easily change that hard coded value or replace it with some kind of count function or a cell reference to a count function on your data sheet, etc etc as needed). It has to start in the second row (as shown in example) or else the offsets of the `ROW()` calls will need to be adjusted. But placed on a new sheet in cell `B2`, this formula will copy down, and read the first 17 columns of the first row of the named range NAMES, then the first 17 columns of the second row, and so forth.

### STEP 3:

I wrote `A2` with a half-baked version of the same formula to just get the first row of the named range 17 times, then the second row etc:

```
=INDEX(COMPANIES,ROUNDUP((ROW()-1)/17,0))
```

That could be rewritten as an index match to get the Company Name value corresponding to the Attendee Name value retrieved in step 2, but I didn't see the utility in that for this use case.

### STEP 4:

Here's the dumb part... Take your output sheet, select all, copy, paste values, filter, delete rows with 0 in column B, remove filter, re-sort, Bob's your uncle.

### POSTSCRIPT

I'm CERTAIN this can be done much more cleanly with a for loop in VBA. You can probably even find code that's quickly adaptable to this exact use case in other questions on this sub. I'm CONFIDENT it can be done without step 4 with a nice formula written by someone more expert than I am. Luckily, step 4 will only take about 10 seconds no matter how big your attendee list is, so quick n dirty works in this case.

Comment: OMG your a boss, however its a short term fix. The spreadsheet is from a google form. im going to create an access database to collect the information to make this data available for next year. google forms data collection is great but leaves alot to be desired...

Answer (score 0):

You could transpose?

So if i am understanding this right when you paste the values the paste in a horizontal line.

If you copy those and in the column you want to paste them in paste special and choose transpose it'll make them in that column but pasted vertically.

Comment: I edited my list in the example to be more clear... transpose will only work for 1 row at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I commented requesting a clarification on exactly how elegant you need this to be... If the answer is "not very", this would be the easy, hacky way that requires a little manual effort, as opposed to a God Formula that just works all the way down (which I'll give some thought to):

[image: screenie]

This assumes you have a reasonable (and known) max number of attendees. Your screenshot showed 6.

The formula for the top left of your destination cell range is:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(L2),"",CONCATENATE($E2,", ",L2))
```

That formula copies/drags, producing the results as shown.

From there it's trivial to copy the entire output block of data (L8:Q12 in my example sheet as shown), paste values, and manually move output columns 2 through 6 underneath column 1 (so in my example sheet select M8:M12, cut, and paste into L13, etc.), then sort alphabetically to push out blank data and you have your list for MM.

Comment: I don't know. This would be absolutely trivial in VB, with which I am barely adequate. That's probably your direction, but not something I'm qualified to offer (good) advice with.

Comment: Hey thanks, I thought of that but there will literally be hundreds of names.
So a manual copy wouldn't work. 
The maximum number of people in my list per company will be 17. right now i can sort by company and show the names in a half baked list...but that forces the blank columns in as well and doesn't work for my intended mail merge with M$WORD.

What I am really after is 2 Columns company name & user that adds the company name if it finds a user write the user in the user column.

if it finds another username in the same company reapeat to the next line.. add user if found
repeat

Comment: I missed the two column requirement. I'm not familiar with this community's protocols. I'm writing a new answer as this one's basically useless

Comment: I wrote a new answer that's much better than this one. I don't know if that means I'm supposed to delete this one (but then what happens to your clarifying comment?) or what, so I'm just leaving it. You can downvote this one and upvote the other one, or something? Are there moderators around here? I don't know. Anyway, read the other answer, I'm pretty sure it solves your issue with virtually no manual labor.